# How can I perform this complex validation in Laravel? (check if a specific row in my table contain a specific token value)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I am pretty new in PHP and moreover in **Laravel**. At this time I am working on a **Laravel 5.4** project and I have the following doubt related to a complex custom validation.

I try to explain my situation.

The user can register on the portal using a registration form. After that the form is submitted the record related to the nes user is written into this **pm_user** table of my database having this strucure:

```
�����¿����¿����������������
� # �   Field  � Null� Key�     Extra     �
�--------------------------------------------�
�  1� id       � NO  � PRI� auto_increment�
�  2� firstname� YES �    �               �
�  3� lastname � YES �    �               �
�  4� email    � YES �    �               �
�  5� login    � YES �    �               �
�  6� pass     � YES �    �               �
�  7� type     � YES �    �               �
�  8� add_date � YES �    �               �
�  9� edit_date� YES �    �               �
� 10� checked  � YES �    �               �
� 11� fb_id    � YES �    �               �
� 12� address  � YES �    �               �
� 13� postcode � YES �    �               �
� 14� city     � YES �    �               �
� 15� company  � YES �    �               �
� 16� country  � YES �    �               �
� 17� mobile   � YES �    �               �
� 18� phone    � YES �    �               �
� 19� token    � YES �    �               �
��������������������������
```

For example this is an inserted record:

```
4   Andrea  Nobili  my-email@gmail.com  AndreaNobili    e2aea7ce7eb227fed4f8e9b80959c327    hotel   <null>  <null>  0   <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>  f63776d15f76dcdc9f3ac8702d12db89
```

As you can see this record contains these 3 informations:

- **The registration e-mail address:** my-email@gmail.com
- **A token automatically generated by the system:**  e2aea7ce7eb227fed4f8e9b80959c327
- **The checked field:** automatically setted to 0 after the user registration.

In particular this **checked*** field setted to 0 means that **the user have compiled the registration form and that has been inserted in the database but that he have yet not confirmed his registration**.

So the process is that: after that the user has been registered on the system he receive an e-mail containing an activation link like this:

```
http://laravel.dev/activate?email=my-email@gmail.com&token=cce0452d95c358b5b3b97fec5662e12e
```

This link contains 2 request parameters (the previous **registration e-mail address** and the **token**).

So the system could check if exist an unactived user into the **pm_user** table) having this e-mail and this token. If a user having this e-mail and this token is found it will be actived (changing the **checked** field value to **1**).

And now there is my doubt.

I have created this **ActivateRequest** class extending the Laravel **FormRequest** class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

/**
 * Class ActivateRequest
 * @package App\Http\Requests
 *
 * Rappresenta una richiesta per l'attivazione di un utente albergatore.
 * La richiestra proviene dal link inviato nella mail e deve contenere come parametri:
 * - Mail con il quale si è registrato l'utente.
 * - Il token generato.
 */
class ActivateRequest extends FormRequest
{

    protected $redirect = 'errors';


    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:pm_user,email',
            'token' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see this class implement this set of validation rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:pm_user,email',
        'token' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

In particular the firs rule check if exist a record with this **email** value into the **pm_user** table. It works fine.

Now I am asking if I perform a more complex rule and check also if **for this specific record** (the one having this e-mail value) if the **token** value (on the token field of this specific row) is the same of the related http request parameter.

Can I perform this kind of complex validation? (it is complex because I am not simply checking if exist a row into the **pm_user** table having this token but I want check if the eventually founded row having the request e-mail have the same token value).

Or have I to perform this check into my controller\service (after that the previous yet implemented validation is passed)?

Comment: You could also do `required|exists:pm_user,token` for the token field, but I would recommend that you do this validation in the controller to make sure that this exact email and token belong to the same record, otherwise the validation can succeed for an email and token from different DB records.

Comment: @TheFallen This was exactly the gist of my question. I was asking if the validation rule provide a way to check the token related to the specific record that was found by the previous rule (related to the specific e-mail) or if I have to implement it manually in the controller

Comment: Laravel does not provide this out of the box, it would be better to run a DB where query for the email and token values.

Comment: @TheFallen Ok tnx, if you post this as response I will accept it